# Polynomial with residual and condition

Tags: polynomials

For which k is the residual when
$q(x)=x^{17}-kx^{15}+(k-2)x^{10}+2x+k^2-2$ is divided by $x-1$ equals to 3?

I did $q(3)=k^2+k(3^{10}-3^{15})+4+3^{17}-2\cdot3^{10}$ and used Reduced quadratic equation with:
$p=3^{10}-3^{15}$ and $q=4+3^{17}-2\cdot3^{10}$

and got a $k_1$ and $k_2$ for solving k as a Reduced quadratic equation.

I then used the equation for q(x) and wrote
$k_1$ instead of k. And a second time but with $k_2$ instead of k.

When i did the division $\frac{x^{17}-k_1x^{15}+(k_1-2)x^{10}+2x+k_1^2-2}{x-1}$ I got the equation to equal to 0. But it's supposed to equal to 3.
Where did I go wrong?

edit: If i take the same steps with q(1) instead of q(3) i get $q(1)=(k-1)(k+1)=3$ which gives me $k_1=2$ and $k_2=-2$. the division is now with $k_1$:
$\frac{x^{17}-2x^{15}+2x+2}{x-1}$

Comment: **Hint :** Show that the residual when you divide $q$ by $x-1$ is $3$ iff $q(1)=3$.

Comment: What is $p(x)$ and why are you computing $p(3)$?

Comment: @lulu sorry the long equation is q(x) and i edited to computing q(3) instead

Comment: Though, as remarked by @TheSilverDoe, it's $q(1)$ that is relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated answer is now correct. In particular, we have

$$\begin{align*} x^{17} - 2x^{15} + 2x + 2 &= (x^{17} - 2x^{15} + x) + (x - 1) + 3 \\ &= x(x^{16} - 2x^{14} + 1) + (x - 1) + 3 \\ &= x((x^2 - 2)x^{14} + 1) + (x - 1) + 3 \\ &= x(x^2 - 1)x^{14} - x(x^{14} - 1) + (x - 1) + 3 \\ &= (x - 1)\left(x^{15}(x + 1) - x(x^{13} + x^{12} + \ldots + 1) + 1\right) + 3\end{align*}$$

For the other value $k_2 = -2$, the polynomial $q(x)$ is now

$$q(x) = x^{17} + 2x^{15} - 4x^{10} + 2x + 2$$

And we have

$$\begin{align*} x^{17} + 2x^{15} - 4x^{10} + 2x + 2 &= (x^{17} + 2x^{15} - 4x^{10} + 2x - 1) + 3 \\ &= (x^{17} - x^{15}) + 3(x^{15} - x^{10}) - (x^{10} - x) + (x - 1) + 3 \\ &= x^{15}(x^2 - 1) + 3x^{10}(x^5 - 1) - x(x^9 - 1) + (x - 1) + 3\end{align*}$$

Which once again is divisible by $x - 1$, since each of $x^n - 1$ is divisible by $x - 1$ (geometric series).

TL;DR your answer is correct.